# Python Global random seed vs Numpy Generator

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am currently using randomness in functions and unit-tests. Moreover sometimes the functions should support `joblib` parallelism. I am wondering what are the issues with using `numpy.random.seed` vs `Generator`?

For example say we have the Generator pattern:

```
# pseudocode
def do_something_with_seed(rng):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(rng)

# you can just call as is
do_something_with_seed(12345)

# I need to generate a seed sequence as I understand, when using parallelism
Parallel(do_something_with_seed(_rng) for _rng in rng.spawn(n_jobs))
```

Next, say we use the `np.random.seed` pattern

```
# pseudocode
def do_something_without_seed(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    ...

# this requires you to always set the global seed before running this function
do_something_with_global_seed(12345)

# when using parallelism
random_seeds = np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.int32).max, size=len(seeds))
Parallel(do_something_with_global_seed(seed) for seed in random_seeds)
```

As I can see it, the performance, functionality is the same as long as you remember to do things properly. Is there any differences or reasons that we for sure need/want to use the `Generator` pattern? What about for unit-testing?

Comment: Is your question: Should one use `np.random.default_rng` over `np.random.seed` and if so, why?

Comment: @jared yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`np.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html):

> This is a convenience, legacy function that exists to support older code that uses the singleton RandomState. Best practice is to use a dedicated `Generator` instance rather than the random variate generation methods exposed directly in the random module.

In other words, the reason you should use the `Generator` version is because it's the newer version which Numpy recommends you use. The old methods are still there for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the documentation. However, I'm asking for explicit reasons because the only reason I see so far is that it is a newer API. But there is no deprecation policy necessarily as far as I can tell and no technical differences that make one worse.

Comment: @ajl123 I don't believe there is any functional difference between the two.

Comment: Then why does numpy recommend a new interface? I guess I'm just confused as to the optimal choice and the documentation reasoning reads a bit abstract and jargon/technical.

Comment: @ajl123 I think the reason is just that it's a better coding paradigm to use. I think that's the same reason they don't recommend using `np.poly1d` anymore but advise using `np.polynomial.Polynomial` (see the note on the [`np.poly1d` documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html#numpy.poly1d)). I think are also some other benefits to this form, such as being able to pass around the `rng`, as discussed in [this](https://builtin.com/data-science/numpy-random-seed) article.